# Web API Controller won't work with POST/PUT/DELETE in ASP.NET Web Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, jquery, webforms

Hi I am having trouble trying to POST/PUT/DELETE objects with the Web API Controller from Ajax. My `Hello` object is getting Post/Put as `id = 0`, `hello = null` no matter what I try.

Anything I am doing that would cause this behavior?

```
//ServicingController.cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace ServicingWebApi.Api
{
    public class ServicingController : ApiController
    {
        public class Hello
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public string hello { get; set; }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return string.Format("id: {0}, hello {1}", id, hello);
            }
        }

        // GET api/<controller>
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        // GET api/<controller>/5
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // POST api/<controller>
        public void Post(Hello stuff)
        {
            Debug.Write(stuff.ToString());
        }

        // PUT api/<controller>/5
        public void Put(int id, Hello stuff)
        {
            Debug.Write(stuff.ToString());
        }

        // DELETE api/<controller>/5
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
            Debug.Write(string.Format("Deleted id: {0}", id));
        }
    }
}
```

ServicingPage.aspx

```
<%@ Page AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ServicingPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="ServicingWebApi.ServicingPage" Language="C#" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {

        //Get
        $('#get').click(function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $.getJSON("api/Servicing");
        });

        //Get Single
        $('#getsingle').click(function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $.getJSON("api/Servicing/" + 1);
        });

        //Post
        $('#post').click(function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var data = JSON.stringify({
            stuff: {
              id: 1,
              hello: "World"
            }
          });
          $.ajax({
            url: "api/Servicing",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
            data: data
          });
        });

        //Put
        $('#put').click(function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var data = JSON.stringify({
            stuff: {
              id: 1,
              hello: "World"
            }
          });
          $.ajax({
            url: "api/Servicing/" + 1,
            type: "PUT",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
            data: data
          });
        });

        //Delete
        $('#delete').click(function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $.ajax({
            url: "api/Servicing/" + 1,
            type: "DELETE",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
          });
        });
      });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
      <button id="get">Get Hello</button>
      <button id="getsingle">Get a Hello</button>
      <button id="post">Post Hello</button>
      <button id="put">Put Hello</button>
      <button id="delete">Delete Hello</button>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Global.asax

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace ServicingWebApi
{
    public class Global : HttpApplication
    {

        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                "DefaultApi",
                "api/{controller}/{id}",
                new {id = RouteParameter.Optional}
                );
        }

        protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

packages.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="AspNetWebApi" version="4.0.20710.0" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="4.0.20710.0" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="4.0.20710.0" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="4.0.20710.0" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="4.0.20710.0" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.0.20710.0" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="4.5.8" />
  <package id="System.Json" version="4.0.20126.16343" />
</packages>
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to stringify your json.

Comment: @jrummell I've tried that, but the controller throws a deserialization error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with this data format

```
var data = JSON.stringify({ id: 1, hello: "World" });
```

Comment: Just a clarification, the default model binder will use the exact deserialized JSON object, so it's trying to map to an object that has a stuff parameter. Since Hello doesn't, it won't map correctly. Implementing it as Claudio has will work

Comment: @ClaudioRedit @AndrewBurgess For anyone that's wondering, when you POST to an ASMX `[Web Method]`  e.g. (`public static void Post(Hello stuff)`)  you need to surround your JSON data to match the parameter's name e.g. `stuff` or it won't deserialize.

Comment: @Romoku i've encountered that same thing with WCF & JSON. MVC is a little more forgiving.